# How do I implement the MPL? What's this "Exhibit A" thingy?

Tags: open-source, licensing, mpl

I'm about to start an open-source project which shall be licensed under Mozilla Public License (MPL).

The problem is, I'm not sure what's this ["Exhibit A"](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/MPL-1.1.html#exhibit-a) thing...

Am I supposed to put that wordy "Exhibit A" in each and every source file contained in the project?

And what about the MPL text proper; must I provide a complete text of the MPL in the root directory of the project?

I'd really appreciate it if someone can point me to a guide on how to *release* software under MPL (as opposed to *using* software with MPL).

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I supposed to put that wordy
>   "Exhibit A" in each and every source
>   file contained in the project?

Yes. From the license:

> You must duplicate the notice in
>   Exhibit A in each file of the Source
>   Code. If it is not possible to put
>   such notice in a particular Source
>   Code file due to its structure, then
>   You must include such notice in a
>   location (such as a relevant
>   directory) where a user would be
>   likely to look for such a notice.

But honestly, you should not use a license you do not fully understand. Consult a lawyer or chose a license that doesn't confuse you.

Comment: Ahh, I must've missed that paragraph. Mostly I understand about the rights & limitations of the MPL. I'll re-read again. Thanks for the answer :)